# Option clash for package geometry

Tags: geometry

I am writing a document in which I wish to switch to landscape part way through.  I thought I could use the line `\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}` to accomplish this but I get an error.  I suspect that this is due to apa6e.  Is there a workaround for this that still allows me to use `apace` and have portrait and landscape in the same document?

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}

\abstract{This is an example of of an abstract in APA.  }
\begin{document}
\title{A Template for APA Papers}
\shorttitle{APA: A Template}
\author{John}
\authornote{\dots}
\date{\today} % or \date{24Jan11} for example
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you planning to use `\newgeometry` to switch to landscape orientation somewhere in the middle of the document (if this is so, you won't be able to do it since `\newgeometry` ignores the landscape option) or do you want your entire document in landscape orientation?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I plan on switching the orientation in the appendix so yes it will switch from portrait in the main document to landscape in the appendix.  I didn't know the call to change layout was `\newgeometry`.  I thought it was `\begin{landscape}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\newgeometry` ignores the `landscape` option so you won't be able to switch from portrait to landscape orientation in the middle of your document. You can use the `landscape` environment from the `pdflscape` package, but this won't take care of headers/footers or page numbers:

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}
\usepackage{,pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\abstract{This is an example of of an abstract in APA.  }

\title{A Template for APA Papers}
\shorttitle{APA: A Template}
\author{John}
\authornote{\dots}
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

The `landscape` environment doen't rotate the header; to keep the header as defined in `apa6e.cls` when in landscape orientation, you could first remove the header/footer using `\pagestyle{empty}` and then use the `background` package to place the header; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgAngle{90}
\SetBgPosition{current page.west}
\SetBgVshift{-1.3cm}
\SetBgContents{}


\abstract{This is an example of of an abstract in APA.  }

\title{A Template for APA Papers}
\shorttitle{APA: A Template}
\author{John}
\authornote{\dots}
\date{\today} 

\makeatletter
\let\StShortTitle\@shorttitle
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{lkadfjsjkdfg}
\subsection{test}

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}
\SetBgContents{%
\begin{minipage}[c][1.2\textwidth][c]{22.8cm}
\noindent\MakeUppercase{\StShortTitle}\hfill\thepage
\end{minipage}%
}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina That works Thank you.  You said, "You can use the landscape environment from the pdflscape package, but this won't take care of headers/footers or page numbers:"   How could I take care of this?

Comment: @TylerRinker: I can't think of a quick fix for that right now; I have an idea, but perhaps it's too complicated. Perhaps someone else can suggest something. If not, then in some hours I can produce the code for my idea. Do you want to keep the standard header/footers?

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina Yes I would like to keep the standard header and footer (in this case there is no footer).  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @TylerRinker: I've updated my answer with an example showing how to obtain the header in the right position when shifting to landscape orientation.

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina Thank you for your time again.  I ran what you had and it squawked when I tried to run exactly what you had asking for american babel so I added: `\usepackage[american]{babel}`.  It runs to 1.40 at the `\begin{minipage}`and throws up an error message: `! paragraph ended before \SetBgContents was complete`

Comment: @TylerRinker: my bad. I uploaded an old testing version of the code; now I have uploaded the right version ;-)

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina Very nice that's perfect.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me figure this out.  I appreciate it a great deal.

Comment: @TylerRinker: you're welcome.